# Can't Install Child Theme "The parent theme is missing. Please install the "Default" parent theme."

Tags: themes, child-theme

This is my first time installing a child theme and I ran into some errors

Here' the style.css

```
/*
Theme Name: WD TechGoStore-child
Theme URI: http://wpdance.com/
Description: Commerce Template
Author: WPDance Team / WPDance.com
Author URI: http://wpdance.com/
Version: 1.0.3
Template: Default Template
Tags: one-column, two-columns, three-columns, left-sidebar, right-sidebar, flexible-width,         custom-menu, full-width-template, rtl-language-support, sticky-post, theme- options,                     translation-ready
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
*/
```

Here's the error:

> The parent theme is missing. Please install the "Default" parent theme.

I've already tried several names for the "Template" but don't know which one should be there as my theme only uses the default template.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change this line: `Template: Default Template` to `Template: wp_techgostore-theme-package`

As per the WordPress Codex,

> The Template line corresponds to the directory name of the parent theme

Comment: Yes. they are installed in wp-content/themes in respective folders as: "wp_techgostore-theme-package" and "wp_techgostore-theme-package-child"
I'm guessing there's something wrong with the Template (?)

Comment: Gotcha! It worked, thank you for that but I encountered another problem.

When previewing the child theme, I went to the about page and the header is broken.

Can you please check if I got the contents of my functions.php correct:
   ` <?php add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts',  'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style',     get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

    }`

Comment: Why are you messing around with the functions.php file ? You should leave it blank, assuming you're editing it in the child theme. What exactly are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: @Boyboy Please don't post code in comments, it is unreadable. This should be an edit to your question. Frankly, this seems more than a new issue which should be asked as a new question

Comment: Just a tip on your formatting, use backticks ( on my keyboard it is under the `~` sign top left under `esc`) to enclose one liner codes and the `{}` in the editor for large code :-) (*PSS!!! you now have enough reputation to post comments to ask for clarity ;-)*)

Comment: @PieterGoosen - I'm still learning the ropes around here and thanks for keeping an eye out for my posts and making my learning process a lot faster :) I've actually learned a lot today and everything you've said so far made a lot of sense (no wonder you've got such a nice profile :) ) Anyway, again, thanks for everything so far and mind you, I'll make sure to stick to all of the tips you've given me so far !